# How to display system log on iPad/iPhone iOS device?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, system, nslog

I want to be able to view all of the NSLog() messages from my App in the App itself.  How do I access the system log of the device?

Answer (score 5):

The answer is at [Using Objective C to read log messages posted to the device console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6144347/using-objective-c-to-read-log-messages-posted-to-the-device-console)