# Apple iOS ASlog, polling for messages.. [code]

Tags: objective-c, c, ios, ipad

After reading these links:
[Using Objective C to read log messages posted to the device console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6144347/using-objective-c-to-read-log-messages-posted-to-the-device-console)
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/asl.3.html

I've successfully posted messages to the ASlog using

```
aslmsg m = asl_new(ASL_TYPE_MSG);
asl_log(NULL, m, ASL_LEVEL_INFO, result);
```

The problem is that when I go to query the log there is extreme lag in getting the results. It seems to be searching everything since I started printing with NSLog earlier today.

My current code to get the information is:

```
q = asl_new(ASL_TYPE_QUERY);
asl_set_query(q, ASL_KEY_SENDER, "db_poc", ASL_QUERY_OP_EQUAL);
asl_set_query(q, ASL_KEY_TIME, "1306768140", ASL_QUERY_OP_GREATER);
```

I'm trying to get my app to send messages to the console (from javascript/UIWebview). I want to then watch the console for these messages so I can send data back to the UIWebviews javascript code..

I wonder are there any extra flags I can set on either send or receive side to speed up things? Also, is there a way to clear this ASlog?

Any ideas..?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried creating your own aslclient using ASL_OPT_NO_DELAY?